# how to reference some values from outside the host.json file

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to be able to reference some values from outside the host.json file but none of the tries worked:

##### Through environment variable

```
{
   "version":"2.0",
   "extensions":{
      "http":{
         "routePrefix":"",
         "customHeaders":{
            "x-version":"%SOMEVERSION%"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Where `SOMEVERSION` was Key for Value defined in local.settings.json

##### Through json ref

```
{
   "version":"2.0",
   "extensions":{
      "http":{
         "routePrefix":"",
         "customHeaders":{
            "x-version":{
               "$ref":"package.json#/version"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: By "outside the host.json " do you mean an arbitrary JSON file that isn't `host.json`? Where is it? What langauge are you writing your Azure function in?

Comment: Yes, I meant arbitrary JSON file, that is not host.json (in my example it is package.json). My az functions are written in ts/js.

Comment: Could you please help me

Comment: But where is this file located? in blob storage?  I can't help you but you can help yourself by being more specific.